# how to redirect complete site from HTTP To HTTPS except for 2 pages in Drupal Site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-6

I have Drupal Site.

I have checked all the below links, but either they don't redirect or I gets an error- Site has too many redirects

- https://www.drupal.org/https-information
- [Redirect all the data served by https to http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473719/redirect-all-the-data-served-by-https-to-http)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24072/how-to-simply-make-the-whole-site-https
- [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)
- [How to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088256/how-to-redirect-from-https-to-http/37088436)
- https://ilovedrupal.com/blog/redirect-http-https-apache-configuration-permanent-redirect-http-https-pages

I need to redirect my complete site HTTP to HTTPS except for two pages:-

- Home - www.hello.com
- Products - www.hello.com/products

The below code-snippet redirects complete site to HTTPS with no issue but I need to escape the Home & products page & for that I have tried about with more than 10-15 combinations.

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hello\.com*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hello.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any Help Highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not the whole site, including those two pages?

Comment: 1)Home page is simple static page, so HTTP will load faster comparison to HTTPS

Comment: 2)The Other page is making an external domain request so in HTTPS , it it blocked, & the user has to approve & then page reloads & then that request is served

Comment: re 1.... except that the logic for identifying whether it should be https or not is also an overhead (compared with simply redirecting everything to https), so any negligeable speed benefit of not serving https for that one page is offset anyway

Comment: re 2.... how is the external domain request being blocked in https?

Comment: @MarkBaker re 2.. not sure but in the second page, map is loaded into iFrame for every product shop

Comment: @MarkBaker, I am getting the below error https://support.schoology.com/hc/en-us/articles/201002223--This-page-is-trying-to-load-scripts-from-unauthenticated-sources-Error-Load-Unsafe-Scripts-

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hello\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://hello.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Nopes..Error Home Page loads fine as desired, but all other pages throws error.. This page has too many redirects

Comment: @just FYI..currently I am testing all these configuration on the subdomain -i.e., www.dev.hello.com

Comment: That can't be a problem with this .htaccess. Because I only avoid `product` and root pages...

Comment: Did you clear your cache or test with other browser ?

Comment: Certainly it is a problem to test with subdomain, because you redirect all to `https://hello.com`...

Comment: I am testing in Chrome Icoginito window, so I think there will be no such cache issue.

Comment: are you sure about the subdomain thing?, as this  seems very risky, directly testing with live site

Comment: You redirect to `https://hello.com/$1`, and if your .htaccess is not ok for the domain...

Comment: I didn't get your last comment, Croises

Comment: Checked.. In that case, on every request, page is redirected to home page

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's try with you , this is your code :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hello\.com*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hello.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

change it to this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hello\.com*
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !products [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://hello.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please try it and let me know if not doing what you want.

Comment: nopes mate..redirects fine for home page but not with the products page and other pages , plus it appends a query string for every page other than home as `www.hello.com/index.php?q=products`